# Flattening JSON into Tabular Structure using Spark-Scala RDD only fucntion

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have nested JSON and like to have output in tabular structure. I am able to parse the JSON values individually , but having some problems in tabularizing it. I am able to do it via dataframe easily. But I want do  it using "RDD ONLY " functions. Any help much appreciated.

Input JSON:

```
  { "level":{"productReference":{  

     "prodID":"1234",

     "unitOfMeasure":"EA"

  },

  "states":[  
     {  
        "state":"SELL",
        "effectiveDateTime":"2015-10-09T00:55:23.6345Z",
        "stockQuantity":{  
           "quantity":1400.0,
           "stockKeepingLevel":"A"
        }
     },
     {  
        "state":"HELD",
        "effectiveDateTime":"2015-10-09T00:55:23.6345Z",
        "stockQuantity":{  
           "quantity":800.0,
           "stockKeepingLevel":"B"
        }
     }
  ] }}
```

Expected Output:

[image]

I tried Below Spark code . But getting output like this and Row() object is not able to parse this.

079562193,EA,List(SELLABLE, HELD),List(2015-10-09T00:55:23.6345Z, 2015-10-09T00:55:23.6345Z),List(1400.0, 800.0),List(SINGLE, SINGLE)

```
def main(Args : Array[String]): Unit = {

  val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("JSON Read and Write using Spark RDD").setMaster("local[1]")
  val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
  val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)

  val salesSchema = StructType(Array(
    StructField("prodID", StringType, true),
    StructField("unitOfMeasure", StringType, true),
    StructField("state", StringType, true),
    StructField("effectiveDateTime", StringType, true),
    StructField("quantity", StringType, true),
    StructField("stockKeepingLevel", StringType, true)
  ))

  val ReadAlljsonMessageInFile_RDD = sc.textFile("product_rdd.json")

  val x = ReadAlljsonMessageInFile_RDD.map(eachJsonMessages => {

        parse(eachJsonMessages)

      }).map(insideEachJson=>{
        implicit  val formats = org.json4s.DefaultFormats

       val prodID = (insideEachJson\ "level" \"productReference" \"TPNB").extract[String].toString
       val unitOfMeasure = (insideEachJson\ "level" \ "productReference" \"unitOfMeasure").extract[String].toString

       val state= (insideEachJson \ "level" \"states").extract[List[JValue]].
          map(x=>(x\"state").extract[String]).toString()
       val effectiveDateTime= (insideEachJson \ "level" \"states").extract[List[JValue]].
         map(x=>(x\"effectiveDateTime").extract[String]).toString
      val quantity= (insideEachJson \ "level" \"states").extract[List[JValue]].
         map(x=>(x\"stockQuantity").extract[JValue]).map(x=>(x\"quantity").extract[Double]).
         toString
      val stockKeepingLevel= (insideEachJson \ "level" \"states").extract[List[JValue]].
         map(x=>(x\"stockQuantity").extract[JValue]).map(x=>(x\"stockKeepingLevel").extract[String]).
       toString

      //Row(prodID,unitOfMeasure,state,effectiveDateTime,quantity,stockKeepingLevel)

    println(prodID,unitOfMeasure,state,effectiveDateTime,quantity,stockKeepingLevel)

      }).collect()

    //  sqlContext.createDataFrame(x,salesSchema).show(truncate = false)

}
```

Comment: What problem is preventing this from working? It's hard to diagnose problem with seeing appropriate exceptions, compiler errors, whatever.

Comment: Thanks for looking at the Problem. The Row Object is not able to tabularize it. Thats the the reason I just put print statement to get hold of problem. The Schema which I defined and the Row() object I am passing are not matching, So I would appreciate any help to solve this .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 versions of solutions to your question.

**Version 1:**

```
def main(Args : Array[String]): Unit = {

  val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("JSON Read and Write using Spark RDD").setMaster("local[1]")
  val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
  val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)

  val salesSchema = StructType(Array(
    StructField("prodID", StringType, true),
    StructField("unitOfMeasure", StringType, true),
    StructField("state", StringType, true),
    StructField("effectiveDateTime", StringType, true),
    StructField("quantity", StringType, true),
    StructField("stockKeepingLevel", StringType, true)
  ))

  val ReadAlljsonMessageInFile_RDD = sc.textFile("product_rdd.json")    

  val x = ReadAlljsonMessageInFile_RDD.map(eachJsonMessages => {

    parse(eachJsonMessages)

  }).map(insideEachJson=>{
    implicit  val formats = org.json4s.DefaultFormats

   val prodID = (insideEachJson\ "level" \"productReference" \"prodID").extract[String].toString
   val unitOfMeasure = (insideEachJson\ "level" \ "productReference" \"unitOfMeasure").extract[String].toString

   val state= (insideEachJson \ "level" \"states").extract[List[JValue]].
      map(x=>(x\"state").extract[String]).toString()
   val effectiveDateTime= (insideEachJson \ "level" \"states").extract[List[JValue]].
     map(x=>(x\"effectiveDateTime").extract[String]).toString
  val quantity= (insideEachJson \ "level" \"states").extract[List[JValue]].
     map(x=>(x\"stockQuantity").extract[JValue]).map(x=>(x\"quantity").extract[Double]).
     toString
  val stockKeepingLevel= (insideEachJson \ "level" \"states").extract[List[JValue]].
     map(x=>(x\"stockQuantity").extract[JValue]).map(x=>(x\"stockKeepingLevel").extract[String]).
   toString

  Row(prodID,unitOfMeasure,state,effectiveDateTime,quantity,stockKeepingLevel)

  })

    sqlContext.createDataFrame(x,salesSchema).show(truncate = false)

}
```

This would give you following output:

```
+------+-------------+----------------+----------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+-----------------+
|prodID|unitOfMeasure|state           |effectiveDateTime                                         |quantity           |stockKeepingLevel|
+------+-------------+----------------+----------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+-----------------+
|1234  |EA           |List(SELL, HELD)|List(2015-10-09T00:55:23.6345Z, 2015-10-09T00:55:23.6345Z)|List(1400.0, 800.0)|List(A, B)       |
+------+-------------+----------------+----------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+-----------------+
```

**Version 2**:

```
def main(Args : Array[String]): Unit = {

  val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("JSON Read and Write using Spark RDD").setMaster("local[1]")
  val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
  val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)

  val salesSchema = StructType(Array(
    StructField("prodID", StringType, true),
    StructField("unitOfMeasure", StringType, true),
    StructField("state", ArrayType(StringType, true), true),
    StructField("effectiveDateTime", ArrayType(StringType, true), true),
    StructField("quantity", ArrayType(DoubleType, true), true),
    StructField("stockKeepingLevel", ArrayType(StringType, true), true)
  ))

  val ReadAlljsonMessageInFile_RDD = sc.textFile("product_rdd.json")    

  val x = ReadAlljsonMessageInFile_RDD.map(eachJsonMessages => {

    parse(eachJsonMessages)

  }).map(insideEachJson=>{
    implicit  val formats = org.json4s.DefaultFormats

   val prodID = (insideEachJson\ "level" \"productReference" \"prodID").extract[String].toString
   val unitOfMeasure = (insideEachJson\ "level" \ "productReference" \"unitOfMeasure").extract[String].toString

   val state= (insideEachJson \ "level" \"states").extract[List[JValue]].
      map(x=>(x\"state").extract[String])
   val effectiveDateTime= (insideEachJson \ "level" \"states").extract[List[JValue]].
     map(x=>(x\"effectiveDateTime").extract[String])
  val quantity= (insideEachJson \ "level" \"states").extract[List[JValue]].
     map(x=>(x\"stockQuantity").extract[JValue]).map(x=>(x\"quantity").extract[Double])
  val stockKeepingLevel= (insideEachJson \ "level" \"states").extract[List[JValue]].
     map(x=>(x\"stockQuantity").extract[JValue]).map(x=>(x\"stockKeepingLevel").extract[String])

  Row(prodID,unitOfMeasure,state,effectiveDateTime,quantity,stockKeepingLevel)

  })


    sqlContext.createDataFrame(x,salesSchema).show(truncate = false)

}
```

This would give you following output:

```
+------+-------------+------------+------------------------------------------------------+---------------+-----------------+
|prodID|unitOfMeasure|state       |effectiveDateTime                                     |quantity       |stockKeepingLevel|
+------+-------------+------------+------------------------------------------------------+---------------+-----------------+
|1234  |EA           |[SELL, HELD]|[2015-10-09T00:55:23.6345Z, 2015-10-09T00:55:23.6345Z]|[1400.0, 800.0]|[A, B]           |
+------+-------------+------------+------------------------------------------------------+---------------+-----------------+
```

The difference between Version 1 & 2 is of schema. In Version 1 you are casting every column into `String` whereas in Version 2 they are being casted into `Array`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this solution. But I want the output records in 2 separate rows, the way which i specified in "Expected Output:" section of the problem statement. is there any way we can get that while passing it Row() object. The output which you mentioned in the Version2 , again needs to be flattened which is doable. But I would prefer the flattened rows while passing it to Row() object. I really appreciate your interest in the problem

Answer (score 6):

HI below is the "DATAFRAME" ONLY Solution which I developed. Looking for complete "RDD ONLY" solution

```
def main (Args : Array[String]):Unit = {

    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("JSON Read and Write using Spark DataFrame few more options").setMaster("local[1]")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)

    val sourceJsonDF = sqlContext.read.json("product.json")

         val jsonFlatDF_level = sourceJsonDF.withColumn("explode_states",explode($"level.states"))
        .withColumn("explode_link",explode($"level._link"))
      .select($"level.productReference.TPNB".as("TPNB"),
        $"level.productReference.unitOfMeasure".as("level_unitOfMeasure"),
        $"level.locationReference.location".as("level_location"),
        $"level.locationReference.type".as("level_type"),
        $"explode_states.state".as("level_state"),
        $"explode_states.effectiveDateTime".as("level_effectiveDateTime"),
        $"explode_states.stockQuantity.quantity".as("level_quantity"),
        $"explode_states.stockQuantity.stockKeepingLevel".as("level_stockKeepingLevel"),
        $"explode_link.rel".as("level_rel"),
        $"explode_link.href".as("level_href"),
        $"explode_link.method".as("level_method"))
jsonFlatDF_oldLevel.show()

  }
```

Comment: great way of thinking :) thanks. My upvote for this answer. :)

Answer (score 4):

`DataFrame` and `DataSet` are much more `optimized` than `rdd` and there are a lot of `options` to try with to reach to the solution we desire.

In my opinion, `DataFrame` is developed to make the developers comfortable viewing data in tabular form so that logics can be implemented with ease. So I always suggest users to use `dataframe` or `dataset`.

Talking much less, I am posting you the solution below using `dataframe`. Once you have a `dataframe`, switching to `rdd` is very easy.

Your desired solution is below (you will have to find a way to read `json` file as its done with `json string` below : thats an assignment for you  :)  good luck)

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val json = """  { "level":{"productReference":{

                  "prodID":"1234",

                  "unitOfMeasure":"EA"

               },

               "states":[
                  {
                     "state":"SELL",
                     "effectiveDateTime":"2015-10-09T00:55:23.6345Z",
                     "stockQuantity":{
                        "quantity":1400.0,
                        "stockKeepingLevel":"A"
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "state":"HELD",
                     "effectiveDateTime":"2015-10-09T00:55:23.6345Z",
                     "stockQuantity":{
                        "quantity":800.0,
                        "stockKeepingLevel":"B"
                     }
                  }
               ] }}"""

val rddJson = sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(json))
var df = sqlContext.read.json(rddJson)
df = df.withColumn("prodID", df("level.productReference.prodID"))
  .withColumn("unitOfMeasure", df("level.productReference.unitOfMeasure"))
  .withColumn("states", explode(df("level.states")))
  .drop("level")
df = df.withColumn("state", df("states.state"))
  .withColumn("effectiveDateTime", df("states.effectiveDateTime"))
  .withColumn("quantity", df("states.stockQuantity.quantity"))
  .withColumn("stockKeepingLevel", df("states.stockQuantity.stockKeepingLevel"))
  .drop("states")
df.show(false)
```

This will give out put as

```
+------+-------------+-----+-------------------------+--------+-----------------+
|prodID|unitOfMeasure|state|effectiveDateTime        |quantity|stockKeepingLevel|
+------+-------------+-----+-------------------------+--------+-----------------+
|1234  |EA           |SELL |2015-10-09T00:55:23.6345Z|1400.0  |A                |
|1234  |EA           |HELD |2015-10-09T00:55:23.6345Z|800.0   |B                |
+------+-------------+-----+-------------------------+--------+-----------------+
```

Now that you have desired output as `dataframe` converting to `rdd` is just calling `.rdd`

```
df.rdd.foreach(println)
```

will give output as below

```
[1234,EA,SELL,2015-10-09T00:55:23.6345Z,1400.0,A]
[1234,EA,HELD,2015-10-09T00:55:23.6345Z,800.0,B]
```

I hope this is helpful

Comment: Hi ramesh, Thanks  a lot. I have already done this solution using dataframes. I am from sql background and daraframe are very easy for me. I thought of learning scala, so wanted to give a try using RDD only functions :)

Comment: Great to hear that @RohanNayak. You must have found better solution then. :) happy for you. Thanks for letting me know. Why don't you post your answer too so that I too learn from it. :)

Comment: HI , I have posted my solution. :)