# Spark DataFrame columns transform to Map type and List of Map Type

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I have dataframe  as below and Appreciate if someone can help me to get the output in below different format.

Input:

```
|customerId|transHeader|transLine|

|1001      |1001aa     |1001aa1  |

|1001      |1001aa     |1001aa2  |

|1001      |1001aa     |1001aa3  |

|1001      |1001aa     |1001aa4  |

|1002      |1002bb     |1002bb1  |

|1002      |1002bb     |1002bb2  |

|1002      |1002bb     |1002bb3  |

|1002      |1002bb     |1002bb4  |

|1003      |1003cc     |1003cc1  |

|1003      |1003cc     |1003cc2  |

|1003      |1003cc     |1003cc3  |

+----------+-----------+---------+
```

Expected OutputSet 1:

```
customerId  headerLineMapGroup 

1001              Map(1001aa -> (1001aa1, 1001aa2, 1001aa3, 1001aa4))

1002              Map(1002bb -> (1002bb1, 1002bb2, 1002bb3, 1002bb4))

1003              Map(1003cc -> (1003cc1, 1003cc2, 1003cc3))
```

Expected OutputSet 2:

```
customerId  headerLineListOfMapGroup 

1001        List[   Map(1001aa -> 1001aa1), Map(1001aa ->1001aa2), Map(1001aa ->1001aa3), Map(1001aa ->1001aa4) ]

1002        List[   Map(1002bb -> 1002bb1), Map(1002bb -> 1002bb2), Map(1002bb -> 1002bb3), Map(1002bb -> 1002bb4)]

1003        List[   Map(1003cc -> 1003cc1), Map(1003cc ->1003cc2), Map(1003cc ->1003cc3) ]
```

Comment: could you please add the text data and remove images. so that it could be searchable and can be copied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution using udf.

```
    val spark = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .master("local")
    .appName("ParquetAppendMode")
    .getOrCreate()

    import spark.implicits._

    val data = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(
      (1001, "1001aa","1001aa1"),
      (1001, "1001aa","1001aa2"),
      (1001, "1001aa","1001aa3")
  )).toDF("customerId", "transHeader", "transLine")

  val toMap = udf((header: String, line: Seq[String]) => {
    Map(header -> line)
  })
  val toMapList = udf((header: String, line: Seq[String]) => {
    line.map(l => Map(header -> l)).toList
  })

  val grouped = data.groupBy("customerId", "transHeader").agg(collect_list("transLine").alias("transLine"))

  grouped.withColumn("headerLineMapGroup", toMap($"transHeader", $"transLine"))
      .drop("transHeader", "transLine")
      .show(false)

  grouped.withColumn("headerLineMapGroupList", toMapList($"transHeader", $"transLine"))
    .drop("transHeader", "transLine")
    .show(false)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: HI Shankar, Thanks a lot . Is it possible to have RDD only solution? Like this. I am able to get headerLineMapGroup but not headerLineListOfMapGroup.                                                                val SparkEvenOutput=  my_dataframe_data_Table.rdd.map ( row=>{
      (  row.getAs[Int](0),
        ( row.getAs[String](1), row.getAs[String](2)  )
        )
    }).groupByKey().map(value=>{
         val customerId=  value._1
         val headerLineMapGroup = value._2.groupBy(_._1).map { case (k,v) => (k,v.map(_._2))}
        Row(customerId,headerLineMapGroup)
      }
      )

Comment: @ Shankar, I have posted one more question in could you please help with this as well .  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44224639/flattening-json-into-tabular-structure-using-spark-scala-rdd-only-fucntion

Comment: If these helped please upvote and mark as an answer, Ok I will surely look at another question.

Comment: Here is the corrected code for your above code.
val SparkEvenOutput= data.rdd.map (row=>{( row.getAs[String](0), ( row.getAs[String](1), row.getAs[String](2) ) )})
    .groupByKey().map(value=>{
    val customerId= value._1
    val headerLineMapGroup = value._2.groupBy(_._1).map { case (k,v) => (k,v.map(_._2))}
    Row(customerId,headerLineMapGroup)
  })