# Create a map column in Apache Spark from other columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I searched this quite a bit but cannot find anything that I can adapt to my situation. I have a dataframe like so:

```
+-----------------+---------------+
|             keys|         values|
+-----------------+---------------+
|[one, two, three]|[101, 202, 303]|
+-----------------+---------------+
```

Keys have an array of strings, values has an array of ints.

I want to create a new column that contains a map of keys to values like so:

```
+-----------------+---------------+---------------------------+
|             keys|         values|                        map|
+-----------------+---------------+---------------------------+
|[one, two, three]|[101, 202, 303]|Map(one->101, two->202, etc|
+-----------------+---------------+---------------------------+
```

I've been looking at this question, but not sure it can be used as a starting point for my situation: [Spark DataFrame columns transform to Map type and List of Map Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44225514/spark-dataframe-columns-transform-to-map-type-and-list-of-map-type)

I need this in Scala please.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a similar udf to the one in the linked question:

```scala
 val toMap = udf((keys: Seq[String], values: Seq[Int]) => {
    keys.zip(values).toMap
  })
```

and than use it as:

```
df.withColumn("map", toMap($"keys", $"values"))
```

Comment: in my case, i have a json string and i need to make it as map type.My Json string is complicated one of type String.How can I do it?

Answer (score 8):

as of Spark 2.4 there is a built in version
`def map_from_arrays(keys: Column, values: Column): Column`
in `org.apache.spark.sql.functions`