# Flatten Json to multiple rows

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, flatten, denormalization

Suppose i have an array inside my JSON and i am trying to flatten it and save it to database. how can duplicate the data i.e., convert that to multiple rows for each element in array? like the example given below. if i dont know what structure i am getting in JSON. how can i achieve this. I found an example on stackoverflow but that helps if you know the structure. how can achieve it without knowing the structure?

[Flattening JSON into Tabular Structure using Spark-Scala RDD only fucntion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44224639/flattening-json-into-tabular-structure-using-spark-scala-rdd-only-fucntion)

```
{ "level":{"productReference":{  

     "prodID":"1234",

     "unitOfMeasure":"EA"

  },

  "states":[  
     {  
        "state":"SELL",
        "effectiveDateTime":"2015-10-09T00:55:23.6345Z",
        "stockQuantity":{  
           "quantity":1400.0,
           "stockKeepingLevel":"A"
        }
     },
     {  
        "state":"HELD",
        "effectiveDateTime":"2015-10-09T00:55:23.6345Z",
        "stockQuantity":{  
           "quantity":800.0,
           "stockKeepingLevel":"B"
        }
     }
  ] }}

+------+-------------+-----+-------------------------+--------+-----------------+
|prodID|unitOfMeasure|state|effectiveDateTime        |quantity|stockKeepingLevel|
+------+-------------+-----+-------------------------+--------+-----------------+
|1234  |EA           |SELL |2015-10-09T00:55:23.6345Z|1400.0  |A                |
|1234  |EA           |HELD |2015-10-09T00:55:23.6345Z|800.0   |B                |
+------+-------------+-----+-------------------------+--------+-----------------+
```

Comment: Are you saying you cannot implement the solution in the linked question? Or do you want to generalize to handle arbitrarily nested JSON?

Comment: I want to generalize to handle arbitrarily nested JSON

Comment: I would start with the solution in the other question as a model. First, scan the JSON data and identify all columnns by name. Then construct your expression using those columns, dropping any "container" columns. You will need to have nested loops to de-normalize the data into your final columns.