# Substitute missing values of campaign_id column with spark Scala

Tags: apache-spark

I have a json file that has the following structure:

```
root
 |-- header: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- version: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |-- makerId: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- envId: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- creationTime: string (nullable = true)
 |-- body: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- playerid: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- hostname: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- playertype: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- timestamp: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- campaignid: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- campaignname: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- duration: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |-- creativeid: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- frameid: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- status: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- ok: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- ko: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- media: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- filename: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- hash: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- timestamp: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- condition: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- origin: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- context: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- key: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
```

Now I want to substitute the missing values of the campaignid ojbet with a constant value = 24737468, but I can not do it either with the map function or with the na.fill()

Could you help me please?

```
import model.domain.PlayLog

import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders


object Hait {

  def main(args: Array[String])
  {
    import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .appName("Spark Load JSON")
      .config("spark.master", "local")
      .getOrCreate()

// For implicit conversions like converting RDDs to DataFrames
    import spark.implicits._
    val schema = Encoders.product[PlayLog].schema
    val rawpop = spark.read.format("json").schema(schema).load("src/main /ressources/raw_pop.json").as[PlayLog]

    val miss_camp = rawpop.filter("body.campaignid is null")
    val final_df = miss_camp.select("body.campaignid").map(r => "24737468" )

 }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace null values in Spark DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33376571/replace-null-values-in-spark-dataframe)

Comment: it does not work for me , I already try na.fill()

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to reproduce the issue with simplified json:

```
{"header": {"version": 1}, "body": {"playerid": 101, "campaignid": null}}
{"header": {"version": 2}, "body": {"playerid": 102, "campaignid": "a"}}
{"header": {"version": 3}, "body": {"playerid": 103, "campaignid": "b"}}
```

Also I've created case classes to convert it to Dataset

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

case class Header(version: Int)
case class Body(playerid: Int, campaignid: String)
case class TestJson(header: Header, body: Body)

val schema = Encoders.product[TestJson].schema
val rawpop = spark.read.format("json").schema(schema).load("/tmp/tests.json").as[TestJson]
```

`rawpop` looks like this

```
+------+-----------+
|header|       body|
+------+-----------+
|   [1]|     [101,]|
|   [2]|   [102, a]|
|   [3]|   [103, b]|
+------+-----------+
```

now lets substitute `null` value

```
val result = rawpop.withColumn("body", struct($"body.playerid",
  when($"body.campaignid".isNull, "default_value").otherwise($"body.campaignid")))
result.show()
```

now it shows

```
+------+--------------------+
|header|                body|
+------+--------------------+
|   [1]|[101, default_value]|
|   [2]|            [102, a]|
|   [3]|            [103, b]|
+------+--------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks you, but I want to substitute the value of the campaignid object in the same json file. with your code i will have a new dataframe structure wich is : root
 |-- campaignid: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CASE WHEN (body.campaignid IS NULL) THEN 24737468 ELSE body.campaignid END: string (nullable = true)

Comment: I've modified my answer, maybe it will help

Comment: Thank you a lot, you're code is usefu. but with the withColumn function i must define the struct of body ?

Comment: Yes, in order to maintain the original structure. Another idea is to flatten json and operate on dataframe without nested structures.

Comment: Could you please give me an example in orther to flatten json...thank you so much

Comment: I would do it manually: `val flat = rawpop.withColumn("version", $"header.version").withColumn("player_id", $"body.playerid").withColumn("campaign_id", $"body.campaignid").drop("body", "header")` And then `flat.na.fill("default_value", Seq("campaign_id")).show()` There are other options: [this nice one](https://www.24tutorials.com/spark/flatten-json-spark-dataframe) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44224639/flattening-json-into-tabular-structure-using-spark-scala-rdd-only-fucntion)